# Layout broken with IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I'm currently dealing with a broken layout of I website in IE7. The layout works fine in IE8, FF, Chrome, Safari but of course not in IE7.

The site can be visited here: http://www.nionwebdesign.com/dev/soon

The problem in IE7 is that the list of images right of the list with links is somehow pushed down to the bottom instead of sticking with the others divs left of it. It looks like a floating/clearing issue but I've tried fixing it for hours but without a result.

Who could take a look and hopefully has the answer to this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have a lot of invalid html in there.  I'd start with cleaning that up and see if it fixes your issue as a side effect.  http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nionwebdesign.com%2Fdev%2Fsoon%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Are you reffering to the div#slider1? If yes, just remove overflow: auto from it!

Comment: @Jawad: You should post that as an answer, I think you've solved it.

Comment: @thirtydot, unfortunately that didn't help, will clean up some more errors, most of them are missing alt-atributes though.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend commenting out all your floats and then re-inserting them one at a time.  When you find the problem float replace it with `display:inline-block` that will usually fix the float issue.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are reffering to the div#slider1, where the div.viewport and the ul.overview have the li and a elements that go to the right and thus not visible, remove the overflow: auto; from the div#slider. Apart from that I dont see much problems except the margins/space between the white torn paper like text.

[IE9](http://i55.tinypic.com/2vaazgz.jpg)

[IE7](http://i51.tinypic.com/16gbbzs.jpg)